# Setting up a block property in custom class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I have a third party API that exposes an `imageBlock` property. I am new to Blocks - how should I set this Block in my class?

```
@property (copy) NSString *(^imageBlock)(NSString *key, NSString *value, BOOL *send);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is correct, however, for sanity and readability I would recommend a `typedef` to create another name for this Block signature:

```
// MyClass.h

typedef NSString * (^ImageBlock)(NSString * key, NSString * value, BOOL * send);
```

Your property declaration then becomes:

```
@property (copy) ImageBlock imageBlock;
```

and any other file which imports this header can see the `typedef`, likewise using it to increase readability.